Default gender in Italian
I've noticed that in Italian the default grammatical gender when referring to some unspecified thing seems to be feminine in some cases but I can't really seem to get an answer when I searched on the internet so I just wanted to know how to pick a gender for unspecified things. For example:

Stop it = Smettila
It's hard to get up so early = È dura alzarsi così presto

But at the same time it's always; lo so, lo penso, lo spero.
So overall I'm a bit confused as to whether this is just some idiomatic case by case basis, a stylistic choice from time to time or are there genuine grammatical rules surrounding this? Thanks for any guidance!

Facts I'll edit that bit out

I wouldn't say that feminine is the default grammatical gender: masculine is more frequent, especially in the sentences like the second one: “È bello/brutto/faticoso/insolito/... alzarsi presto”. It's just that “è dura” is an idiomatic phrase in itself. You might answer to, say, “Come va con lo studio?” with just “Eh, è dura”. Perhaps a remnant from “è una cosa dura” or something? Just a guess.

Not much about "default", but about the assumed subject. Having "la gente", "una persona" as good common generic name, we may see it on some expressions.
